# fql for place name and place id useing com.restfb

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, restfb

I have coordinates as latitude and longitude, I want to get a list of place from facebook using facebook query (FQL). Does anyone have an example of how to to that? I am also fine with using the graph api

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with the Graph API:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=10000&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAB7yPm6SoZAeJyU7MnYXqllWwcTLQDZB2g96QCmpb2B2QDAWtPfCkRJtCN8tnPbDrTqaZA6M9fmHdm1FXB0kbmaXEShDwZDZD
(Via the [online documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#places))

I can't get it to work with FQL, although the correct syntax appears to be:

```
SELECT name,description,geometry,latitude,longitude,checkin_count,display_subtext FROM place WHERE latitude=40.797702 AND longitude=-105.587082
```

([Try it](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20name,description,geometry,latitude,longitude,checkin_count,display_subtext%20FROM%20place%20WHERE%20latitude=40.797702%20AND%20longitude=-105.587082&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAB7yPm6SoZAeJyU7MnYXqllWwcTLQDZB2g96QCmpb2B2QDAWtPfCkRJtCN8tnPbDrTqaZA6M9fmHdm1FXB0kbmaXEShDwZDZD))